# Copy-item cmdlets only working correctly when the destination folder exists

Tags: powershell, recursion, copy-item

I want to copy folders with their contents to a remote computer using a PSSession and Copy-item. When running the script for the first time it has to create the destination folder, it does so correctly and then is supposed to dump the folders with their contents inside into the destination folder. What it is instead doing is dumping two of the folders correctly and then dumping the contents of the third folder, not the folder itself. When I run it a second time without deleting the destination folder, everything runs fine.

I have tried using various different parameters, including `-container` but it doesn't seem to help at all. Here is where I use the function in my code, I use a lot of environment variables and variables in general because this needs to be a script that can be put anywhere and work.

```
if (Test-Path -path "$env:TEMP\VMlogs") {
        Write-Host "I'M GONNA SEND IT!"; Pause
        Copy-Item -path "$env:TMP\VMLogs\*" -tosession $Targetsession -destination $Destination`_$Source -force -recurse
        Write-Host Logs copied sucessfully!
        Remove-Item "$env:TEMP\VMlogs" -recurse
    } else {
        Write-Host "There was an issue copying logs!"
        Pause
        Exit
```

What I expect is that the folders are put into the destination folder with their intact structure but instead this only happens on the second running of the script, after the destination folder has already been created.

Comment: have you looked at `Get-Help Copy-Item -Parameter container` yet? ///// also, PLEASE fix your code ... markdown is not _that_ difficult ... [*grin*]

Comment: Yes I have, like I mentioned using the switch doesn't fix the issue. And I corrected the code snippet, forgot to add the `.

Comment: ah! i  had so much trouble trying to read your unformatted code that i missed the `-Container` reference. [*blush*] you may need to simply add a step that creates the top level destination dir.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but it seems really strange that I have to do that for the cmdlet to work properly

Comment: i cannot think of WHY it may be needed -  the `-Force` & `-Container` parameters seem to cover what you want - but it looks like you may just need to go with what works. ///// i would seriously consider `robocopy`, tho, since it is highly optimized for copying files & structure - and it works very neatly from inside PoSh ... [*grin*]